# std::expected support in clang

Tags: c++, clang

the following program

```cpp
$ cat try.cpp
#include <expected>
int main() {
  using T = std::expected<int, char>;
  return 0;
}
```

Fails to compile with clang

```
 $ clang++ -std=c++2b try.cpp
try.cpp:3:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
    3 |   using T = std::expected<int, char>;
```

The reason being that the expected header has the following guard

```
#if __cplusplus > 202002L && __cpp_concepts >= 202002L
```

However clang has this

```
$ clang++ -dM -E --std=c++2b try.cpp | grep __cpp_concepts
#define __cpp_concepts 201907L
```

This is clang compiled from current git tip, version 17. The standard library installed in on a current Arch linux stable that has gcc at version 13.1.1

What am I missing, is there a way (besides redefining that macro) to cleanly use the expected header on clang? I see on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) that clang 16 is supposed to have support for this class.

Edit: found https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/62801 describing the exact same problem, I guess I'll have to switch std libraries

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/7G1xroKEM according to [this table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23#C.2B.2B14_library_features) it should work since clang 16. Apparently clang comes with older version of `libstdc++`, so you may switch to: `-stdlib=libc++` to make it work.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the edit in the question and removed my answer. You may want to provide an answer yourself and put your Edit into the answer instead of in the question.

Comment: If I'm bothering to compile with clang, I always also use libc++.

Comment: I don't want to use libc++ in my project nor I care much about clang. The problem is that youcompleteme uses clang for completion and this issue renders the whole vim+youcompleteme unusable cause clang finds an infinite number of unexistent errors.

Comment: So you're having a tooling issue. In any case, clangd can take the flags that are needed. Although the big picture view is that it's a bit silly to rely on a tool that's not in your pipeline to tell you about your code. I'm still surprised that gcc hasn't provided a LSP of its own.

Comment: @MarekR, I'm probably being overly pedantic, but strictly speaking, clang doesn't come with any version of libstdc++.  libstdc++ is the GNU implementation of the C++ standard library.  libc++ is clang's implementation of the C++ standard library.  If you are on a system that has g++ installed as the default compiler, then libstdc++ is the system's default C++ standard library, and clang will use it.  Also note that on some systems, `-stdlib=libc++` won't work until one explicitly installs libc++, since there are cases in which it won't be installed by default when installing clang.

Comment: have you solved this problem,? i have the exact problem